# Sorted Dictionary customize key look-up for efficiency

Tags: c#, dictionary, binary-search-tree

Recently, I learned that the [Sorted Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) class implements binary search over the keys, and I wanted to use this to my advantage. I am making a [piecewise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise#Notation_and_interpretation) linear function class that represents a collection of lines over a bunch of intervals.

I defined an `Interval` class like this:

```cs
public class Interval : ICloneable, IComparable, IComparable<Interval>
{
    public Interval()
    {

    }
    public Interval(double start, double end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    // Properties
    public double Start { get; set; } = double.NaN;
    public double End { get; set; } = double.NaN;
    public double Span => End - Start;

    // Methods
    public object Clone() => MemberwiseClone();

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return Start.CompareTo(obj);
    }

    public int CompareTo([AllowNull] Interval other)
    {
        if (Start < other.Start)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (Start > other.Start)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(double x) => Start <= x && x <= End;
    public override string ToString() => $"[{Start}, {End}]";
}
```

And the `SortedDictionary` in question works like this in the piecewise function class:

```cs
public class PiecewiseLinearFunction : ICloneable
{
    ...
    // The dictionary
    public SortedDictionary<Interval, Line2D> Functions { get; set; } = new SortedDictionary<Interval, Line2D>(); // Where Line2D is just a class that contains a function definition for a line

    // Methods
    public Interval FindInterval(double x)
        => Functions.Keys.Where(interval => interval.Contains(x)).FirstOrDefault();
    public double Solve(double x)
    {
        var interval = FindInterval(x);
        if (interval != null && Functions.ContainsKey(interval))
        {
            return Functions[interval].Solve(x);
        }
        else
        {
            return double.NaN;
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the `PiecewiseLinearFunction.FindInterval(double x)` method linearly searches through the dictionary's keys in order to find the interval that contains (or doesn't contain) `x`, which can be used for binary look-up, but that obviously defeats the purpose of doing the binary look-up at all.

I was wondering if I could somehow make the dictionary look up the `double x` value instead, and do a binary search over the intervals while checking if `Interval.Contains(double x)` is `true` or `false` to decide if there is a valid interval (key) and a corresponding line that can be used to get the function value at `x`.

In other words, is there a way to search with a predicate, something like `FindInterval(double x) => Functions.Keys.FindBinary(i => i.Contains(x))`.

Comment: You'll face with precision loss for double values and should use some kind of tolerance

Comment: I agree, and in the full code there are plenty of improvements to be made as well, but I'm mainly concerned with the look-up at the moment.

Comment: I don't think the fact that `SortedDictionary` uses a binary tree internally helps you here. All the consumer of the class knows is that the dictionary keys are sorted. You want to perform a binary search on the data, but `SortedDictionary` doesn't provide indexed access to the data, so isn't suitable for binary search.

Comment: So you mean I'd be better off writing a class that itself contains an interval and a line, and write a custom binary search for a collection of that class?

Comment: If the intervals can overlap I you need an encapsulating data-structure keeping track of extra information to be able to support binary-search, just a custom interval class and binary search are not enough.

Comment: A dictionary uses a hash lookup that reduces time from N/2 to Log(N).  So definitely a dictionary help if you have an exact key.  You are using contains which is different.  I think you need to bin you data to speed up results by using Quantization : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing)

Comment: @Knoop though I haven't implemented any checks, I intend to never have them overlap but you're right, I should make sure of that explicitly.

Comment: @jdweng Well, the dictionary only accepts `Interval` objects as keys, whereas ideally I could use a predicate while searching. I'll update my question to include that.

Comment: The simple method with double is multiply the double by a constant like 1000 and round to an integer.  Then the integer is the key to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the intervals don't overlap there is actually not really a need for a custom binary search.

First of all it helps if we make `Interval` comparable to `double`:

```
public class Interval: IComparable<double>
{
    public double Start { get; set; }
    public double End { get; set; }

    public bool Contains(double x) => x >= Start && x <= End;
    public int CompareTo(double other)
    {
        if (Contains(other))
            return 0;
        return other < Start ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Now we create a `List` extension so we're able to do binary search with other types then just the type of the list:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static int BinarySearch<T, TU>(this List<T> sortedSource, TU val) where T : IComparable<TU>
    {
        return sortedSource.BinarySearch(default(T), Comparer<T>.Create((item, _) => item.CompareTo(val)));
    }
}
```

And now we can test it like this:

```
var list = new List<Interval>
{
    new Interval
    {
        Start = 0,
        End = 4
    },
    new Interval
    {
        Start = 6,
        End = 7
    },
    new Interval
    {
        Start = 10,
        End = 12
    }
};

var index = list.BinarySearch(6.0d); //index = 1
var interval = index < 0 ? null : list[index]; //interval = [6, 7]

index = list.BinarySearch(9.0d); //index = -3
interval = index < 0 ? null : list[index]; //interval = null
```

Comment: Oh, my bad, I just noticed you'd posted an answer, let me give it a shot real quick!

Comment: So if I use this implementation, I might as well use a regular `Dictionary<Interval, Line2D>` since that's a much faster look-up, right? The way I do currently do it would have a complexity of `O(n log n)` whereas combining binary search with a regular dictionary would have a complexity close to `O(log n)`?

Comment: @JansthcirlU That is correct, binary searching in the list and then doing a lookup in the dictionary combined would be expected `O(log n)`. Maybe wrap the whole thing in a custom datastructure that holds both the sorted `List<Interval>` and the `Dictionary<Interval, Line2D>` to centralize the adding, removing etc. Then you can also use the BinarySearch for optimized insertions in the sorted `List<Interval>`.